# Time values from timestamp [sqlite3, Knex]

Tags: mysql, node.js, sqlite, knex.js

How can i store only IST time values like HH:MM in created_at row, values generated from `timestamp` are in UTC and DATE+TIME format

```
exports.up = function(knex) {
    return knex.schema.createTable('tbl_xyz', (table) => {
        table.increments('id').primary();
        table.timestamp('created_at').defaultTo(knex.fn.now());
        table.string('date');
        table.string('url');
        table.string('tags');
    });
};
```

Comment: Do you want to save just the HH:MM or both date and time in IST timezone?

Comment: @fortunee only HH:MM time

Comment: What db are you using MySQL or Postgres?

Comment: Ooops I see it now, you're using sqlite

Comment: You might wanna consider using the `moment.format()` feature

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with [`date-fns`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/date-fns):

```js
const dateFns = require("date-fns")
```

Then, on table def:

```js
table.timestamp('created_at').defaultTo(dateFns.format(knex.fn.now(), 'hh:mm'))
```